# PFFile conforming to NSCoding

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nscoding

I need to store some instances of a subclass of `PFObject` I made, with the help of `UserDefaults`. The thing is, it crashes the moment it tries to encode (and decode) a `PFFile`.

I looked it up and found that in order to have a `PFFile` archived, it too should conform to the `NSCoding` protocol and apparently it doesn't. So I added these files to my project https://github.com/eladb/Parse-NSCoding.

Now everything works, except when I call `retrieveAdsFromDevice()`. Then I get this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000c386f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0051bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d5ab735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e023f44 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e009ed6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e00bda8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001099c5685 _decodeObjectBinary + 2409
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001099c3c67 _decodeObject + 246
    7   Foundation                          0x00000001099c3b63 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 205
    8   NUP                                 0x000000010626f768 $S3NUP4NPAdC5coderACSgSo7NSCoderC_tcfc + 3576
    9   NUP                                 0x000000010627015f $S3NUP4NPAdC5coderACSgSo7NSCoderC_tcfcTo + 47
    10  Foundation                          0x00000001099c5685 _decodeObjectBinary + 2409
    11  Foundation                          0x00000001099c485f -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1684
    12  Foundation                          0x0000000109958c1c -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 198
    13  Foundation                          0x00000001099c5685 _decodeObjectBinary + 2409
    14  Foundation                          0x00000001099c3c67 _decodeObject + 246
    15  Foundation                          0x00000001099c3b63 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 205
    16  Foundation                          0x00000001099c2e64 +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:] + 84
    17  NUP                                 0x00000001061d9b87 $S3NUP11NPAdManagerC21retrieveAdsFromDeviceyyF + 887
    18  NUP                                 0x00000001062d2a26 $S3NUP18HomeViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 438
    19  NUP                                 0x00000001062d2c44 $S3NUP18HomeViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
    20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116b3f4e1 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1186
    21  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116b3f940 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    22  NUP                                 0x00000001063349c5 $S3NUP22RootPageViewControllerC21viewDidLayoutSubviewsyyF + 7237
    23  NUP                                 0x0000000106336444 $S3NUP22RootPageViewControllerC21viewDidLayoutSubviewsyyFTo + 36
    24  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117648914 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1824
    25  QuartzCore                          0x000000010af8ab19 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 175
    26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010af8f9d3 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    27  QuartzCore                          0x000000010af087ca _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 342
    28  QuartzCore                          0x000000010af3f97e _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 576
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001171792d0 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 139
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df6a62c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df69de0 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df64654 __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df63e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001109251dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    35  UIKitCore                           0x000000011715e81d UIApplicationMain + 140
    36  NUP                                 0x00000001063b8a44 main + 68
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ee27575 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my class:

```
class NPAd: PFObject, NSCoding {
    @NSManaged var type: String
    @NSManaged var imageFile: PFFile
    @NSManaged var link: String
    @NSManaged var brandName: String
    @NSManaged var brandIcon: PFFile

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(type, forKey: "type")
        aCoder.encode(imageFile, forKey: "imageFile")
        aCoder.encode(link, forKey: "link")
        aCoder.encode(brandName, forKey: "brandName")
        aCoder.encode(brandIcon, forKey: "brandIcon")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()

        type = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as! String
        imageFile = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imageFile") as! PFFile
        link = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "link") as! String
        brandName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "brandName") as! String
        brandIcon = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "brandIcon") as! PFFile
    }
}
```

and this is how I store and retrieve my data:

```
func storeAdsToDevice(_ adsToView: [NPAd]) {
    let archivedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: adsToView)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedData, forKey: "AdsToView")
}

func retrieveAdsFromDevice() -> [NPAd] {
    let archivedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AdsToView")

    if let archivedData = archivedData as? Data {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedData) as? [NPAd] ?? []
    }

    return []
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install your Pod but it seems to be missing a file:

```
[!] Error installing Parse-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/73/wg47j7351qx65npm3ncb9nw80000gn/T/d20190927-45089-1q578tl/file.zip http://parse-ios.s3.amazonaws.com/f1992e7a501affcc1906429e3690bae5/parse-library-1.2.21.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

Am I missing something?
In my Podfile:

```
pod 'Parse+NSCoding', '~> 0.1.4'
```

Also tried without the version and got the same problem.

Comment: It's not my pod, I just found it... Have you tried cloning the project and adding the files manually?